# Ready-to-Use Database models example

Tags: database-recommendation, database-design, database-theory

Where can I find ready-to-use database models ?

I don't need a database with data in it, but only schemas (UML diagrams). Perhaps something like the [data models at this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20191123175222/http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/), but much more complex and real world.

Comment: When I attempt to view one of those models I get the following warning: www.databaseanswers.org contains content from novikkoll.in, a site known to distribute malware. Your computer might catch a virus if you visit this site...

Comment: link works, I relay don't know where is the problem at your computer. I am using Ubuntu and Firefox.

Comment: Your link works for me but clicking on the links to one of the models (e.g. Customers at a Bank) brings up the warning. I'm using Windows 7 and Chrome.

Comment: FWIW - Of the examples of models I've seen at http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm my impression has always been that they are very simplistic and not representative of good real world data models.

Comment: http://databaseanswers.org is now down. I have switched the link in the question to point to a recent archive copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20191123175222/http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/

Comment: For what it's worth I like databaseanswers.org. Where as 'ready to use' is too much to ask, I definitely think it is a fairly detailed 'generic starting point' that you can customise or compare your database model too.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

David Hay's

- [Enterprise Model Patterns](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1935504053). This is a beast of a book, but has some great patterns.
- [Conventions of Thought](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0932633749). More stuff on MRP.
- [A Meta-Data Map](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120887983) . Haven't read this one.

Len Silverston's

- [Data Model Resource Book Vol. 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471380237). Your main data model patterns.
- [Data Model Resource Book Vol. 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471353485). Case studies by industry.
- [Data Model Resource Book Vol. 3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470178450). A deeper explanation of Vol 1.

Michael Blaha's [Patterns of Data Modeling](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439819890). This one has some interesting temporal, graph, and tree models.

Martin Fowler's [Analysis Patterns](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201895420). This one skims some of the other patterns, but gives accounting a solid treatment.

They are all well-rated, and I have read all but one, and they are all very good. Several of them are available on [safaribooksonline](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/search?q=data%20model).

Also, OASIS's [Universal Business Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Business_Language), [schemas](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/UBL-2.1.html#S-UBL-2.1-BUSINESS-OBJECTS)

Answer (score 4):

- If it's more complex than the free data models you've mentioned, then I'd suggest it is a custom model for your requirements.
- Anything complex would most likely be commercial, proprietary, or otherwise someone's IP.
  For example, a data model for an MMORPG or a derivatives trading system.

What are you trying to do anyway?