# Digital content eCommerce schema advice?

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd, architecture, application-design

I don't have much experience designing databases, I'm looking for some advice on my design from more seasoned designers/developers. I'm developing a digital content eCommerce store which will be desktop based and mobile based similar to iTunes.

Schema
[image: Schema Design]

The store will most work like iTunes, it's just that it's focused on music at the moment. I'm not sure if I should explain each table responsibility. Users can reload monetary credits to their profiles from an external application.

Please advice if this design will work and is sufficient. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get yourself a good [data model pattern book](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831#23831).
2. Accept the fact that most relationships are many-to-many.
3. Read up on table inheritance and the Party/Party Role model.

Some starting points:

1. An order has many line items, which belong to a product
2. A product will probably belong to multiple categories
3. A product will likely have more than one artist

Comment: Thanks for giving me direction. :-)

Can you please elaborate on this point further, im not if I understand you "An order has many line items, which belong to a product"

Comment: Well, someone might buy a few items in a single order. You probably want to encourage this in fact. So there could be many line items for a given order. A line item is for a product quantity at a given unit price.

Comment: I guess this makes sense for billing purposes and physical good where user might buy more than one quantity.

But here it's a digital content store, so the user will be buying just one item in terms of quantity always. It doesn't have a cart as well, as soon as the user clicks the "Buy Now" button, I want to complete the transaction, basically bill the user and start the download.