# Best approach for Legal/Natural can have many Orders

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-theory, referential-integrity

I'm working on this model:

[image: DB Model]

where as you may see one `NaturalPerson` can have many `Order` and the same for `LegalPerson` the only difference between `NaturalPerson` and `LegalPerson` are a few so in that case will be better to repeat all the `Order` fields in `NaturalPerson` and in `LegalPerson` or will be better to leave as I have right now? My only concern around my model is if is not this a serious inconsistency to leave an empty column at `Order` table (legal_person or natural_person depends on which the Order belongs to) as the Orders belongs to a Natural or a Legal but not both of them?

What will yours do in this case?

**1st approach**

For all the pros mentioned at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3579462/719427) I tough the best here is go with **Class Table Inheritance** so if I understood the explanation my model now is this one:

[image]

It's right?

**2nd approach**

See my own answer below ...

Comment: A pointer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database that may be a helpful analysis. Slide here: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back/32

Comment: @jynus can you take a look to my edit and come back with some feedback around it?

Comment: ReynierPM No, your edit is not on the right path. Use @user16484's suggestion or your original design. `order_id` has no place in the persons tables. Can an order be associated with many persons? Is a person associated with only one order?

Comment: @ReynierPM, I do not fully understand your requirements, but if there a 1:N relationship and you want to follow the mentioned good patterns for having foreign key constraints (and not your original design), you would need an extra link table.

Comment: @ypercube no one order belongs only to one person but one person could have zero or many orders. I added a new approach, take a look

Comment: @jynus I added the extra table as issued by user16484 is this one right?

Comment: Your second approach looks ok, asuming that `person_id` are both PK and FK. (that's what both user18484 and Neil suggested, more or less). I'd prefer if you deleted this from the question and wrote it as an answer. (You can answer your own questions here!)

Comment: My only other suggestion/rant is to use `person_id`, `order_id` as names everywhere (throw those `id` into the fire).

Comment: @ypercube what you mean with use `person_id` and `order_id` as a names? you mean rename the field as `person` and `order`?

Comment: I mean the column `id` in `persons` table to renamed as `person_id`. And the `id` in `orders` tables to be renamed `order_id`. It's a personal preference - although shared I think by many, not to have columns named just `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Neil and user16484 suggestions also ypercube and jynus and good practices at DB modeling, I come with this model

[image]

This is what they talked about

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative to your solution. I suppose your `id` columns are just for mysql internal use, so you could have:

- `person table` with `id`, `name`, and `type` which would be a bit or 1 character to say if it is a natural or legal person. This table will connect to `order table` where you will only need one column - `person_id`
- On `natural_person table` you remove the `name` column and connect it to the `person table`
- On `legal_person table` you remove the `name` column and connect it to the `person table`

Comment: I can't do that since both holds different values see the new model, I made a typo in the first one, my bad

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not right.

There should not be an order_id in a person table. Generally speaking, is an order id an attribute of a person? No.

I'd start with Single Table Inheritance, as it's simpler:

```
create table parties (
  party_id int primary key,
  type smallint not null references party_types(party_type_id), --1=individual,2=organization
  name text not null,
  ...
);
```

Also, multiple parties play multiple roles in a Sales Order, but I guess you're talking about the Customer. In that case:

```
create table sales_orders (
  order_id int primary key,
  customer_id int not null references parties(party_id),
  ...
);
```

There is a customer_id attribute on the sales order, with a foreign key pointing to the parties table.

You should probably read one of the books listed here:

[Ready-to-Use Database models example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831#23831)

Comment: Thanks I'll read those recommended books in order to improve my knowledge and learn new things, I've the model