# Database design: Is there a much better way on this current relationships?

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams

I have a `faculty`and `student`table to store each information, respectively. I made a `contact`table to store the contacts of either faculty or student. I would like to use the `contact` table as a generic one, means it can be used by either `faculty` or `student`.

My table diagram is something like this.

I compressed faculty and student into a `USER table` and have an `account type` in that table to know whether it is a `faculty` or `student` type of user. Then the `USER` table will have a one is to many relationship with the contact table.

> Student
>
> Faculty
>
> Contacts
>
> Student & Faculty = User table 
>  User table -----<- Contact table

Comment: In practice what you're proposing is good. A good practice is to also have an AccountType table that will contain the friendly description of the account type and an integer. Then use that integer in the User table in the account type field. Any indexing on that field, in the user table, will be more efficient. You only need to join to the AccountType table when you care to display the friendly name. Also modifications to AccountType values will be much more efficient.

Comment: Is there an another way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True story: I was a student at my school, then I taught there. Then one of the teachers took my class. You need to account for silliness like this.

And a faculty member or student isn't necessarily a user either.

Use table inheritance.

`Faculty : Individual : Party`

`Student : Individual : Party`

Where `:` means inherits.

`Party hasOne User`

A `contact` is a relationship between two parties:

`Party hasMany ContactRelationships belongsTo Party`

See [Ready-to-Use Database models example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831#23831) for reference models.

Comment: This is my first time to hear that. Thank you for that, sir! :)