# Database design - need someone to guide me

Tags: database-diagrams, database-design

I'm probably doing this wrong, but here it goes.

I'm trying to build something like very basic CRM. I know there are plenty of them, but I want something to learn actually.

**Requirements:**

- Some companies are never contacted before. That's why I created two additional tables `contact_emails` and `company_emails`.
- The contacted company may have assigned contact (person).
- A person can have phones and emails.
- One person can be assigned to multiple companies
- One company can have multiple persons

**Diagram:**
[image]

**Questions:**

- Am I on the right track?
- What can be improved and how?

Answer (score 1):

1. Learn [Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) (aka subtype/supertype)

   ```
   Individual   : Legal Party (":" meaning "inherits")
   Organization : Legal Party

   Email          : Address
   Phone          : Address
   MailingAddress : Address
   WebURL         : Address

   LegalParty -< PartyRelationships >- LegalParty
   LegalParty -< ContactInfo >- Address
   ```
2. Read up on [existing data model patterns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/ready-to-use-database-models-example/23831#23831). Don't re-invent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

@RottenUser, you seem to be on the right-track, as far as I can confirm this, having looked at your db schema.

You asked: What can be improved and how?

Well, company_phones isn't really need, I think. As you can add a column in the phones table or contact_phones, sort of to filter out if the phone is private (i.e. personal mobile)/public etc.